# Casting ListBox.SelectedItems in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, listbox

Trying to add multiple selected items from one listBox to another.

```
rightBox.Items.AddRange(leftBox.SelectedItems)
```

However, this throws an error because `AddRange()` is looking for `ListBox.ObjectCollection` but, `leftBox.SelectedItems` is `ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection`

How can I cast `SelectedObjectCollection` to an `ObjectCollection`?

Or is there a better way to be doing this?

Comment: Are you sure this is WPF? Because `AddRange` doesn't exist in WPF `ListBox.Items` !

Comment: @user2946329 sorry, meant to put winforms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The add-range function will also accept the type of object[], so you can cast your selected items and add them like so:

```csh
rightBox.Items.AddRange(leftBox.SelectedItems.Cast<object>().ToArray());
```